# How to make multi-line text in JavaScript alert() dialog selectable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert, microsoft-edge, chromium

I am using the alert() dialog to display error messages to the user in my application.

One of the alert dialogs is much clearer when using specifically placed line breaks for 2+ lines of text.

Unfortunately, when I show an alert() dialog while using "\n" or "\r" the text of the alert is no longer selectable for copy/paste operations.

This behavior only seems to be present in Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge (I haven't tried it on Opera, but I'd be willing to bet any Chromium based browser would show the same behavior).

This behavior is not present in Firefox.

Version of Chrome used for testing: Version 108.0.5359.72 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Version of Edge used for testing: Version 107.0.1418.62 (Official build) (64-bit)
Version of Firefox used for testing: 107.0.1 (64-bit)

Here is a simple code snippet that demonstrates the issue:

```
function delay(milliseconds){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
    });
}

async function init(){
        alert("this text is selectable");
        await delay(500)
        alert("this text is not selectable \nbecause of the newline");
        await delay(500)
        alert("this text is not selectable \rbecause of the return");
}

init();
```

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1dejgr3/)

I have also tried using 
 tags, but that seems not to provide any new-line behavior in an alert() dialog.

Comment: You might want to consider raising a bug report for this at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/entry

Comment: It seems that it's a chromium issue which hasn't been fixed: [link1](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1346156&q=alert%20%5Cn%20select&can=2), [link2](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=958139&q=alert%20%5Cn%20select&can=2). You can also star the issue to add a vote and get notifications.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your comments! I'm glad that it seems to be an issue in Chromium and I will definitely add a vote to those issues.